# Selenium Webdriver Java can't handle javascript:void(0), opens new tab

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I have problem with Selenium WebDriver, which I am using to automate some tasks. I use Java Selenium.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>2.47.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm creating product on my website, after positive validation, I get product ID. Then I'm trying to search created Product using created id and open link with product.

```
<a role="textbox" href="javascript:void(0);" class="drilldown" name="Name" tabindex="-1">Name of product</a>
```

Unfortunetly, webdriver opens "javascript:void(0);" page on the new tab. When I am trying to click manually on link everything works fine and product page opens.

When I'm trying to find existing product on my website without creation process everything also looks fine and webdriver behave as I want. My webpage is very complicated and a lot of content is created dynamically using javascript/ajax etc.

I know that I didn't give many details. I am trying to solve this problem. Only WebDriver reset and opening new session helps for now.

Thanks for your answers, It's my first serious problem that I can't solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to click using JavascriptExecutor as it directly working on HTML DOM. Feel free to locate element in below code according to your convenience:

```
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("Your Xpath"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```